# Skew Button, not Text, in loop

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I found a few answers on this but none that involve a loop.  I'm not sure how to separate the text, and button - and then combine them... which is oddly the only way i can think of doing this.  But I'm sure some one of you guys will know the answer to this off the bat.

I want to skew the button, but not the text.

Here's CSS:

```
.btn-primary-2 {
    transform: skew(-15deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  yellow, red) !important;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 16px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 10px 3px ;
}
```

Here's the

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <%= link_to cat.name, listings_path(:category => cat), class: "btn btn-primary-2" %>
<% end %>
```

I have made a few attempts but not point in posting them cbecause they didn't work and irrelevant.

I want to skew the button, but not the text.
Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

**UPDATE:**

I have made progress.  The button itself doesn't work, it only works when i click on the text itself.  How to i attach it?

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <div id="btn-cat"><div id="btn-text"><%= link_to cat.name, listings_path(:category => cat, class: "btn btn-cat") %></div></div>
<% end %>
```

I have used "button_to" instead of link_to but it somehow goes to the same link as link_to, but receives errors such as "param is missing or the value is empty: listing" - I have recently changed my models/controller and am still working on it.. but regardless, the other link works with link_to (going to the same url)

Comment: write text in a `span` because text inside the div so parent property it will take.

Comment: If i change the btn-cat to a span, nothing changes.  if i change the btn-text to a span, the text then adopts the classes of the btn-cat and skews.... or did i mistaken what you said ?

Answer (score 1):

Here I write the sample code hope this will help you.

```css
.btn-primary-2 {
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, red) !important;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 10px 3px;
}

.btn-primary-2 span {
  display: block;
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-primary-2">
  <span>SENDHERE</span>
</div>
```